# C# WPF Loop & Delete Checked ListView Items

Tags: c#, wpf

As someone who has recently switched from WinForms to WPF, I'm still struggling and going nuts trying to figure out a way to **loop through** and **delete checked ListView items**.

This method gives me error: "ListView does not contain a definition for CheckedItems..."

```
    if (lvFilesList != null)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvItem in lvFilesList.CheckedItems)
        {
            lvItem.Checked = False;
        }
    }
```

My XAML Code:

```
            <ListView Height="400" Width="400"
              Name="lvFilesList"                       
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="chk" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="File" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding File}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Author" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Group"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: A ListViewItem is not a checkbox, you should navigate the children of the ListViewItem until you find the checkbox that you are looking for

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Could you please show me the complete code for your method and let me know where you use it?

Comment: I import items from a Data Table into my ListView.

Answer (score 3):

It looks odd that the ItemsSource of your ListView is directly bound to the current DataContext by

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

The DataContext would usually hold a view model object with a collection-type property like

```
public class Item
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    // other properties like ID, File, Author
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
}
```

and the Binding would be

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
```

Then the view model could have a method that deletes all checked items, like

```
public void DeleteCheckedItems()
{
    var checkedItems = Items.Where(item => item.IsChecked).ToList();

    checkedItems.ForEach(item => Items.Remove(item));
}
```

---

Note that you usually assign an instance of the view model class to the DataContext of your main view, e.g. in the MainWindow constructor:

```
private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    viewModel.Items.Add(new Item { ID = 1, ... });
    viewModel.Items.Add(new Item { ID = 2, ... });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I tried, it didn't remove any items. I'm afraid if it's because I import items from a DataTable into the listView?

Comment: The code in this sample removes elements from the Items collection. Anything else that should possible be done seems out of the scope of the question, since you haven't mentioned it.

Comment: What do I have to do now?

Comment: How could we possibly tell that? Did you make sure you initialize the ListView by only adding elements to the view model Items collection, instead of perhaps adding them directly to `lvFilesList.Items`? In an MVVM approach you must not directly access the Items collection of a data-bound ListView. When you import items from a database, add them to the Items collection of the view model. Move the whole "data import" code to the view model class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll start learning the basics of WPF.